# Google reCaptcha not loading inside a cross domain iframe on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, cors, recaptcha

I have an iframe that contains a form. My parent page lies at domain thishost.com and the iframe source lies at alternate.thishost.com.
The form contains captcha which is implemented using Google's reCaptcha API, V1.
When I load the parent page on IE, the captcha doesn't load and shows the following error on console:

**SCRIPT5: Access is denied.**

I tried loading the page on IE 9,10 and Edge and faced the same issue.

I also enabled cross domain requests for the iframe's source and still faced the same issue.

Any pointers on the issue?

Comment: How did you "enable cross domain requests"?

Comment: I added
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
to my virtual host conf